# Char counter working in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I've implemented a character counter function that works in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox. I've got it on my VB.NET page. Can you help me understand why it works in Chrome but not Firefox?

```
 <br>Other comments (max 250 characters):
<br>
<asp:TextBox ID="OtherComments" runat="server" MaxLength="250" 
    onblur="javascript:CharCounter(this.id);" 
    onkeyup="javascript:CharCounter(this.id);" style="height:50px; width:450px;" 
    TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
<br>
    <asp:Label ID="lblCounter" runat="server" Text="250 chars remaining"></asp:Label>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function CharCounter(textId) {
        var totalchar = '<%= OtherComments.MaxLength %>';
        var txtbox = document.getElementById(textId);
        var lbl = document.getElementById('<% =lblCounter.ClientID %>');
        if (txtbox.value.length > totalchar) {
            txtbox.value = txtbox.value.substring(0, totalchar);
        }
        lbl.innerText = (totalchar - txtbox.value.length) + " chars remaining";
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: `.innerText` is non-standard. Use `.textContent` instead. If you need to support IE8, you can patch it into `HTMLElement.prototype`

Comment: or innerHTML - works everywhere

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a string with an integer. That could be the problem. It's also better to use innerHTML instead of innerText. InnerText isn't supported in some browsers. 
Hopes this fixes your problem.

```
function CharCounter(textId) {
        var totalchar = <%= OtherComments.MaxLength %>;
        var txtbox = document.getElementById(textId);
        var lbl = document.getElementById('<% =lblCounter.ClientID %>');
        if (txtbox.value.length > totalchar) {
            txtbox.value = txtbox.value.substring(0, totalchar);
        }
        lbl.innerHTML = (totalchar - txtbox.value.length) + " chars remaining";
}
```